# Мини поисковик по базе на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3, re

Ради прикола решил я сделать мини поисковик по базе данных(аниме), но я заметил один очень неприятный дефект. Взять К ПРИМЕРУ аниме Пять невест, если ввести "Пя" результат будет, но если ввести "Пять" он ничего не выведет. Я подозреваю что дело в шаблоне(я использовал модуль re). Что я хочу от программы? Я хочу чтобы она выводила данные по названию, которое ввёл пользователь, например : "Пять" и результат по запросу. Код внизу. Помогите пожалуйста.

Содержимое файла originalAnimeName:

```
Невеста чародея — Мальчик с Запада и всадник мглы
Комета Люцифер
Пощади меня, великий господин!
Руководство гениального принца по вызволению страны из долгов
Невероятное приключение ДжоДжо: Каменный океан
Повседневная жизнь в фотостудии времени
Повседневная жизнь бессмертного короля 2
Атака титанов: Финал. Часть 2
Бегущий по лезвию: Чёрный лотос
Кровь Триединства
Евангелион 3.0+1.01: Как-то раз
Повариха в доме майко
Топить в вине бушующее пламя печали
Бог войны
Кагинадо
Хеталия: Мировые звёзды
Путь домохозяина 2
Глубинное безумие: Потерянное дитя
Импульс мира 3
Принцессы-полудемоны — Вторая глава
Клинок, рассекающий демонов: Бесконечный поезд
Билд Дивайд: Чёрный код
Покемон: Секреты джунглей
Визуальная тюрьма
Далёкий паладин
Лучший в мире ассасин переродился в другом мире аристократом
У Коми проблемы с общением
Гордость оранжевых!
Платиновый предел
Такт. Опус Дестини
Воины Пограничья
Плод эволюции
Луна, Лайка и Носферату
Реинкарнация безработного: История о приключениях в другом мире 2
Один из отвергнутых: Изгой 4
Восемьдесят шесть 2
Девочка-батарейка из мира-перевёртыша
Заметки Теслы
Ночь по ту сторону треугольного окна
Давайте тоже слепим кружку 2
Отборочный проект
Тотальный гарем
Звёздные войны: Видения
Рейтинг короля
Чёрные метки
Мув-Лув: Альтернатива — Полное затмение
Мув-Лув: Альтернатива
Мутэкинг: Танцующий герой
Голубой период
Вечноцветущая сакура
Клинок, рассекающий демонов: Квартал красных фонарей
Мешки и пушки!
Мой сэмпай раздражает!
Божественная семейка
Доки, ты справишься!
Сказка о девушке эпохи Тайсё
Этот вампир постоянно умирает
Девушки-пони: Ёнкома
Девушки-пони: Славное дерби 2
Кафе из другого мира 2
Кафе из другого мира
Любит — не любит
Меня выгнали из гильдии героев, потому что я был плохим компаньоном, поэтому я решил неспешно жить в глуши
Агент времени: Спецвыпуск
Повесть о доме Тайра
Девочка, которая видит это
Записи о магии: Девочка-волшебница Мадока★Волшебство — Гайдэн 2
Магистр дьявольского культа 3
Я в тебе не сомневаюсь
Дефектные: Доступ запрещён
Унеси меня на Луну OVA
Ремейк нашей жизни: Рекап
Моё семнадцатое лето
Истребитель демонов: Поезд «Бесконечный»
Фена: Принцесса пиратов
Скрытые вещи. Фильм
Граница пустоты 8: Эпилог
Граница пустоты 7: Теория убийства — Часть 2
Граница пустоты 6: Мелодия забвения
Маг на полную ставку 5
Граница пустоты 5: Спираль парадокса
Граница пустоты 4: Храм пустоты
Мегатон
Так сложно любить отаку OVA
Красавица-воин Сейлор Мун: Вечность 2
Граница пустоты 3: Оставшееся чувство боли
Граница пустоты 2: Теория убийства  — Часть 1
Граница пустоты 1: Сад грешников
Я, Цусима
D_Cide: грёзы
Красавица-воин Сейлор Мун: Вечность
Месть Масамунэ OVA
Месть Масамунэ
Морская академия. Фильм
Морская академия OVA
Морская академия
Хроники расхитителей гробниц: Волшебное дерево Циньлина
Джахи не будет отчаиваться!
Смертоносный герцог и его чёрная горничная
Повесть о конце света
Дореми: В поисках волшебства
Когда плачут цикады: Выпускной
Детектив уже мёртв
Приоритет чудо-яйца: Спецвыпуск
Готика
Акватоп белого песка
Сумеречный разум 2041
Девушка из оперы!!
Парни из магазинчика
Я стою на миллионах трупов 2
Мифический дух: Хроники
Мои девушки
Битва через 5 секунд после встречи
Лунное путешествие приведёт к новому миру
Персиковый мальчик с того берега
Восемьдесят шесть: Спецвыпуск
Божества Идатэн в мирном поколении
Незнакомец на берегу моря
Тяжкий труд в подземелье
Моя реинкарнация в отомэ-игре в качестве главной злодейки 2
Агент времени: Поединок за руку дочери
Герой-рационал перестраивает королевство
Живая любовь! Суперзвезда!!
Почётная ученица в школе магии
Мемуары Ванитаса
Комендант общежития богинь
Размеренная жизнь чит-фармацевта: Создание аптеки в альтернативном мире
Ремейк нашей жизни
Лунный проект 2
Дракон-горничная госпожи Кобаяси 2
Ре-Мейн
Алый Нексус
Первый отряд: Момент истины
О моём перерождении в слизь 2. Часть 2
Двуличный братик Урамити
Фантастические дети
Госпожа Кагуя: в любви как на войне OVA
Клинок и душа
Прощай, мой дорогой Крамер: Первое касание
Низкоуровневый персонаж Томодзаки OVA
Рок-шоу! Звёзды!
Сонни Бой
Остров гигантских насекомых. Фильм
История семьи Аркана
Рыцари и магия
Сакэ Вакако
Ясукэ
Агент времени
Зачем Вы здесь, учитель?! Спецвыпуск
Вайолет Эвергарден. Фильм
Вечно ленивый Танака
Небесное вторжение
Феи Ранмару: Мы спасём твоё сердце
Может, я встречу тебя в подземелье? 3 OVA
Подземелье Токио
Девушки и танки: Война тайяки!
Гармония
Девушки и танки: Финал. Часть 3
Девушки и танки: Финал. Часть 2
Девушки и танки: Финал
Эхо террора
Афросамурай: Воскрешение
Афросамурай
Годзилла: Точка сингулярности
Цестус: Римский боец
Добро пожаловать в ад, Ирума! 2
Сальто назад!
Романтическая комедия, в которой подруга детства ни за что не проиграет
Токийские мстители
Путь домохозяина
Победа боевых атлетов ReSTART!
Не издевайся надо мной, Нагаторо
Повелитель тьмы: Другая история мира 2
СД Гандам: Герои мира
Восемьдесят шесть
Мир ограничивается тобой. Анимация
Айтю: На полпути к идолу
Другой мир
Необычное такси
Дневники слизи
Корзинка фруктов: Финал
Для тебя, Бессмертный
Я побрился. Затем привёл домой старшеклассницу
Семь рыцарей революции: Преемник героя
Хори и Миямура
Хикару и Го
Виви: Песнь флюоритового глаза
Прощай, мой дорогой Крамер
Пламенное кабадди
Чистый звук
Красавчики-детективы
Супер Каб
Давайте тоже слепим кружку
Убивая слизней 300 лет, сама того не заметив, я достигла максимального уровня
Карточные бои «Авангард»! Замещение
Нулевой Эдем
Смута: Принцесса снега и крови
Диназенон
Судьба/Ночь схватки: Прикосновение небес 3
Не называй это любовью!
Патриотизм Мориарти 2
Дом теней
Моя геройская академия 5
Дарованный. Фильм
Синий луч отражения
Зомбилэнд-Сага: Месть
Комбатанты будут высланы!
Дракон в поисках дома
Всемогущая магия святого
Мегалобокс 2
Что, если чрезвычайно развитая ролевая игра с полным погружением вызывает большее привыкание, чем реальность
Красный Марс
Би: Начало 2
Орган геноцида
Работяга
Война двенадцати
Отикоборэ: Фруктовый пирог
Шаман Кинг (2021)
Доктор Рамунэ, специалист по мистическим болезням
Миёри и волшебный лес
Новый мастер кулинарии 2
Волшебник-воин Орфен 2
Деревенская глубинка 3
Токийское восьмибалльное
Панда большая и маленькая
Проза бродячих псов: Шуточные истории
Фуука
Доктор Стоун: Каменные войны
Лазурный путь: Малый вперёд!
Заметки Ятогамэ 3
Маг-целитель: Новый старт
Лог Горизонт 3
Приоритет чудо-яйца
Экс-Арм
О моём перерождении в слизь 2
Реинкарнация безработного: История о приключениях в другом мире
Инцидент Кэмоно
Импульс мира 2
SK8: На скейте в бесконечность
Хоримия
Сильнейший герой, обученный в тайном подземелье
Да, я паук, и что?
Проект Скард: Шрам Прэйтер
Путь назад
Низкоуровневый персонаж Томодзаки
Пять невест 2
Небесное бюро дизайна
Лагерь на свежем воздухе 2
Волейбольный клуб старшей школы Сэйин
Клетки за работой: Тёмная сторона
Клетки за работой 2
Обещанный Неверленд 2
Сага о Гортензии
Девушки в доспехах
Выдающиеся звери 2
О моём перерождении в слизь: Хината Сакагучи
Гэкидол
Пикник в Потусторонье
История о пареньке из деревни, расположенной перед сложнейшим подземельем
Семь смертных грехов: Яростное правосудие
Ведущие звёзды
Re: Жизнь в альтернативном мире с нуля 2. Часть 2
Первый микс
Рандеву с пулей: Смерть или пуля
Боевой континент 5
Боевой континент 4
Боевой континент 3
Боевой континент 2
Боевой континент
Пожиратель богов: Пролог
Пожиратель богов
Любовь под гипнозом
Магистр дьявольского культа: Чиби
Благословение небожителей
7 семян 2
Я пытался уговорить её в догэдза: Эпизод 13
Я пытался уговорить её в догэдза
Путешествие к бессмертию
Штурмовые ведьмы: Дорога на Берлин
Дворянство: Пробуждение
Дворянство: Начало разрушения
A3! Осень и зима
Бедственная правда
Разминка!
Сон в замке демона
Самурай-гимнаст
День, когда я стала Богом
Королевский рейд: Наследники воли
Дворянство
Сжечь ведьму
Патриотизм Мориарти
Магическая битва
Когда плачут цикады: Разгадки
Когда плачут цикады
Золотое божество 3
Живая любовь! Школьный клуб айдолов
Ми-ми-ми-мишка
Держись крепче! Скалолазки
Инуяся: Последний акт
Принцессы-полудемоны
Унеси меня на Луну
Я стою на миллионах трупов
Путешествие Элейны
Полководцы Сигрдрифа
Гипнотический микрофон: рэп-баттл дивизионов, Райм-Анима
Штурм Лили: Букет
Догма дракона
Последнее поле брани между тобой и мной, или Святая война сотворения мира
Западные ворота парка Икэбукуро
Кошечка из Сакурасо
Из нового света
Бездарная Нана
Избранный богами
Атака титанов: Финал
Когда плачут цикады: Карма
Может, я встречу тебя в подземелье? 3
22/7: Эпизод 13
Адати и Симамура
Акудама Драйв
Непутёвый ученик в школе магии: Гость
Закрыты в рамках. Геном [Прямая трансляция]: Узлы воспоминаний
Сводки бюро расследований
Ты единственная, кто любит Великого Меня?! OVA
Шерлок из Кабуки-тё OVA
Сквозь слёзы я притворяюсь кошкой
Волейбол!! К вершине 2
Моя геройская академия: Сделай это! Тренировка на выживание
Шестая зона
Олимпия Киклос
Кизнайвер
Легенда о Касиве
Любовь и продюсер
Невеста титана
Гибель Японии 2020
Как и ожидалось, моя школьная романтическая жизнь не удалась 3
Удзаки хочет тусоваться!
Мастера Меча Онлайн: Алисизация — Война в Подмирье. Рекап
Деми хотят поболтать
Питер Грилл и время мудреца
Пламенная бригада пожарных 2
Непризнанный школой владыка демонов
Жизнь без оружия 2
Маг на полную ставку 4
Джибиэйт
Доктор для девушек-монстров
Девушка на час
Бог старшей школы
Дека-данс
Бюро паранормальных расследований Мухё и Родзи 2
Лазурные огни
Формирование извращённой силы
Великий притворщик
Смертельный бильярд
Парад смерти
Re: Жизнь в альтернативном мире с нуля 2
Гостиница Окко
Баки 2
Сумеречная Дева и Амнезия: Дева и экзорцизм
Сумеречная Дева и Амнезия
Ты и я 2
Ты и я
Красная черта
Мастер китайского альманаха
Аргонавис из «Ура мечте!»
Легенда о Белом Коте
Буря потерь: Истребление цивилизации
Домовой дух Татами
Дюрарара!! 2: Продолжение — В ритме влюблённых
Дюрарара!! 2: Финал — Дюфуфуфу!!
Дюрарара!! 2: Финал
Дюрарара!! 2: Наследие — Горячее набэ согревает мне сердце
Дюрарара!! 2: Продолжение
Дюрарара!! 2: Наследие
Дюрарара!! Спешлы
Дюрарара!!
Народные сказки из будущего
Руководство сотен демонов
Один из отвергнутых: Изгой 3
7 самураев
Бог обмана
Мой «комплекс братика» морали не остановить! — Спешлы
Мой «комплекс братика» морали не остановить!
В те годы, когда я работал в зоопарке
Детективное агентство дятла
Дропкик злого духа: Эпизод 12
Дропкик злого духа 2
Вечеринка мёртвых: Истязаемые души
Вечеринка мёртвых: Пропавшая запись
Цугумомо 2
Цугумомо OVA
Цугумомо
Спой мне «Yesterday»
Кулинарные поединки Сомы: Пятое блюдо
Ванпанчмен 2: Спецвыпуски
Небесный избранник из древних сказаний
Госпожа Кагуя: в любви как на войне 2
Богатый детектив. Баланс: Неограничен
Поэзия теней
Волшебник-воин Орфен: Спецвыпуск
Рыбалка для школьниц после занятий
Корзинка фруктов 2
Связь принцесс: Повторное погружение
Царство 3
Проект «Белая Кошка»
Глейпнир
Моя реинкарнация в отомэ-игре в качестве главной злодейки
Гяру и динозавр
Арте
Литераторы и алхимики: Шестерни судей
Слушатели
Совершенно новый зверь
Башня Бога
Восьмой сын, я так не думаю!
Сакура: Новая война миров
Тамаёми
Волны, слушайте меня
Скрытые вещи
Президент, пришло время для битвы!
Чистюля! Аояма
Небо в цвету!
Фантазия Гранблю 2: Глава Джиты
Ты же любишь мамочку, удары которой бьют по площади двойным уроном? OVA
Этот замечательный мир! Багровая легенда
Семёрка идолов: Вибрато
Семёрка идолов
Семёрка идолов 2
Любовь с незапамятных времен
Власть книжного червя 2
Власть книжного червя OVA
Шоколад Купидона 2
Шоколад Купидона
Вперёд, ко вселенной!!
Магические войны
Добро пожаловать в NHK
Руководство по семенам фей
Антидот
Ты – хозяин, я – слуга
Эй, люби меня всерьёз!
Повседневная жизнь бессмертного короля
Монополия моего героя
Ну не может моя сестрёнка быть такой милой: Спешлы
Ну не может моя сестрёнка быть такой милой: Анимированный комментарий
Ну не может моя сестрёнка быть такой милой 2
Ну не может моя сестрёнка быть такой милой
По велению адской сестры: Отбытие
По велению адской сестры: Взрыв OVA
По велению адской сестры: Взрыв — Спешлы
По велению адской сестры: Взрыв
По велению адской сестры OVA
По велению адской сестры: Спешлы
По велению адской сестры
Удар крови: Королевство валькирии
Удар крови II
Удар крови III
Удар крови IV
Удар крови: Потерянное Святое Копьё
В подземелье я пойду, там красавицу найду! 2 OVA
Убийца гоблинов: Корона гоблина
Мастера Меча Онлайн: Алисизация — Война в Подмирье 2
Плод Грисайи
Рай Грисайи: Спешлы
Плод Грисайи:
```

```
import sqlite3
import re

# ищем аниме по названию
def getName():
    with open("originalAnimeName.txt",'r') as f:
        orig = f.read()
    inp2 = input(">>> ")
    # создаём шаблон
    s = re.compile(r".*\w*{}\w.*".format(inp2), re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
    # проходим по переменой s и наполняем массив
    names = []
    for mt in s.findall(orig):
    names.append(mt)
    if names == []:
            print(f"Ничего не могу найти по запросу \"{inp2}\"")
    return names


# функция поиска по имени
def searchByName():
    db = sqlite3.connect('myAnimeDataBase.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # получаем массив из getName()
    for name in getName():
        alist = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM animes WHERE name='{}' ORDER BY name""".format(name)).fetchall()
        for anime in alist:
            value = (str(anime[1]) + " --- " + str(anime[3]) + "год" + "\n" + str(anime[0]) + "\n" + str(anime[2]) + "\n" + str(anime[4]))
            print("*"*100)
            print(value)
    db.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    helpList = """
        1. Найти.
        2. Выход.

    """
    print("#"*26,"Чего хотите?","#"*26)
    print(helpList)
    inp = input(">>> ")
    while inp != "2":
        if inp == "2":
            break
        elif inp == "1":
            print(documentation)
            break
        elif inp == "1":
            searchByName()
            break
        else:
            print()
            print("#"*23,"Не могу понять вас(","#"*22)
            break
```

Comment: блин, а как содержимое бд вам показать?

Comment: я думаю, ошибка скорей всего в s = re.compile(r".*\w{}\w.*".format(inp2))